# Date picker fields are being empty on return page.

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using date picker in text box pop up :

```
 $(document.getElementById('<% = Clstdtval.ClientID %>')).datepicker();
```

I am doing search operation based on the date and with the results I am navigating to another page.

While returning back to the search page the datepicker fields are empty.

Comment: You can add the data picker value to a session and set it again to your picker field.

Comment: @Soombina kundi: Session is useful and it depends where you are using the same. Hidden fields and session are useful based on context where they are being used.

Comment: Thank you @ Biz apps.. I can able to retrieve the values.
@Soombina kundi and Iti Tyagi: please let me know which one i need to choose or is there any good solution for the problem

Comment: i agree but session will lack values sometimes when the page is not postback. @ItiTyagi

Comment: since you are using js my best advice is to store and retrive values in hidden fields@user96888